# Is behaviour of putting & after command is shell specific?

Tags: bash, shell, background-process, zsh

I have observed in zsh if I run a command like,

```
some_command &
```

and close the terminal, it would kill the process started by some_command.

While it doesn't happen with bash.

So, I'm curious if the behaviour of putting "&" after command is shell specific?

Comment: unrelated, but seems like you might be interested in `screen`, which will keep your processes alive

Comment: `tmux` is also pretty good (and doesn't act as weird for me as `screen` does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the exact specifics on background vs detach from controlling terminal vs process group, etc are shell-specific. You should look up the `nohup` command for some additional detail.